# IOS how to set date format

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have a string like this

```
NSString *datestr = @"2013-08-06T03:51:54+00:00";
```

I try to set dateformat as below:

```
NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [dformat dateFromString:datestr];
```

But the date will be nil, so, can anyone tell me how to set the dateformat, thx!

Comment: Not a day without `NSDateFormatter` dupe!!

Comment: I want in “2015-12-31T01:45:00.5876454+05:30” this fromat ?

Comment: this question's title is more search friendly than the previously answered question and the other question does not have an accepted answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];

NSDate *date = [dformat dateFromString:datestr];
```

Add `ZZZ` to the end of your formatter.

Comment: -1 because wrong. open Xcode and try yourself.

Comment: I had try it, it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Try out this code

```
NSString *datestr = @"2013-08-06T03:51:54+00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];

NSDate *date = [dformat dateFromString:datestr];
```

**use small z** where z give you - with the specific non-location format. Where that is unavailable, falls back to localized GMT format. Use one to three letters for the short format or four for the full format. In the short format, metazone names are not used unless the commonlyUsed flag is on in the locale

for zone for more info about Date Format Patterns in objective c refer this link 
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns hope this will help you

Comment: Also keep in mind that your format strings can be magically rewritten in some regions sometimes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

try below:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-08-06T03:51:54+00:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

NSDate *date;
NSError *error;
[formatter getObjectValue:&date forString:dateString range:nil error:&error];
```